# Apply custom function to multiple groups in R

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a custom function across all groups of my dataset.

I tried applying the below custom function across all groups but its being applied on overall data set. But if I break my data into multiple groups & apply each group to this function its working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. You just need to apply your function for each group. The `purrr` library makes this pretty easy.

## Libraries:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
```

## Main function:

Takes group name and full data set as arguments, then filters by that group. Then makes calculations and returns them as a dataframe.

```r
width <- function(Group.Name, data){
  # limit to rows for that group
  df<-data %>% filter(Group == Group.Name)
  
  i.mins  <- which(diff(sign(diff(c(Inf, df$Value, Inf)))) == 2)
  
  i.mx <- which.max(df$Value)
  
  i <- sort(c(i.mins, i.mx))
  
  ix <- i[which(i == i.mx) + c(-1, 1)]
  
  # put results in dataframe
  df <- data.frame("Group" = Group.Name, "Value_1" = ix[1], "Value_2" = ix[2])
  
  # format Group Col
  df$Group <- as.character(df$Group)
  return(df)
}
```

## Looping through groups with `purrr`

```r
# unique group names we need to loop through for calcs
Group.Names <- unique(data$Group)

# take each name and use the width function
# then put results together in one datframe
Group.Names %>% map_df(~ width(Group.Name = .x, data = data))
```

## Results:

```r
   Group Value_1 Value_2
1 Group1      16      22
2 Group2       4      12
3 Group3       2      15
```

Note: the `.x` notation just tells map to put the `Group.Names` object as the first argument in our width function